# using nine-patch image as Background of Button android

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have created the following Nine-Patch PNG Image

[image]

but when I add it as a background for a button I have got the following result :

[image]

as you can see the picture not fill all the button Background !

here is the XML Layout File :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ninepatchimage"
        android:text="Click ME" />
</LinearLayout>
```

can any one tell me why ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the image it appears that the image ins't being parsed as a 9patch, it should be saved as `img.9.png` if not it will appear as a normal image

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe try without the padding

Comment: the selected image is saved as img.9.png, but when I add it to Project as Icon Set Image, I checked the name of image and it was img.png in Drawable folders !!! is the problem here ???

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be like the image above

Comment: You can drag the image directly into the folder

Comment: Ok I will try that :) but in which Drawable folder should I drag the picture into ??

Comment: just drawable, it will go for all densities, unless you have language specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays in AndroidStudio, you can just take any image from the resources and right-click it and choose *"Create 9-Patch file"* and then configure it using the built in 9-Patch editor, as expained [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch).