# How do I apply the default "blue button"-style used on android first start?

Tags: android, button, colors

Namely, how do I apply [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLspj.jpg) button style? I'm refering to the blue button in the lower right corner.

Answer (score 2):

create a `drawable` folder in res folder then create XML file and call it `button_background`
within the XML file you will define the shape of the button, like what is the color, and corner, stroke and padding everything you can do here. The following code is similar to the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#56b7cc" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#70daf1" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#68c8dd"
            android:endColor="#70daf1"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#70daf1" />
        <corners
            android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

then in your layout give the button the following:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="107dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="ok" />
```

I made fixed width and height so it look as the picture, the most important attribute is

```
android:background="@drawable/button_background"
```

you can modify it as much as you want by changing the colors, padding read more about it [here](http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/). hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Its android `ShowcaseView` functionality. You can refer it [here](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView)

Comment: ShowcaseView looks interesting, but I can't find much documentation. After importing ShowcaseView and the dependencies mentioned and adding the JARs to the buildpath, I get "ViewTarget cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have much idea about it as i have not tried it yet. But Definitely you will get some good online examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only button style, you need create own button style and based on, for example:

**on nine-patch image** ([using nine-patch image as Background of Button android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007462/using-nine-patch-image-as-background-of-button-android), [Button with 9-patch image background doesn't stretch correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360478/button-with-9-patch-image-background-doesnt-stretch-correctly)),

**or based on shape** ([How to create custom button in Android using XML Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507351/how-to-create-custom-button-in-android-using-xml-styles))

Answer (score 1):

style.xml

```
<style name="Button.Blue" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/xbg_blue_button</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

xbg_blue_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_focused_holo_light" />
<item                                                                                          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_light" />
```

drawables:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54394631/buttons.rar